# Python invalid literal for int() with base 10: '+'

Tags: python

So first, the assignment given was to make the function "compute" solves it and returns the value. If the given sting is not a valid equation, returns "None"

```
def compute(side):
    val=int(side[0])
    lastop=0
    for i in range(1,len(side)):
        if side[i].isdigit():
            if lastop=='+':
                val+=int(side[i])
            elif lastop=='-':
                val-=int(side[i])
            elif lastop=='x':
                val*=int(side[i])
            elif lastop=='/':
                val/=int(side[i])
        else:
            lastop=side[i]
    return val
```

So at this point the value would be returned. But if the function is run for ("22-11x4"), it gives 0 not 44. **I've turned them into integers and why would they still give me the wrong value?**

```
def evaluate():
    val=int(side[0])
    lastop=0
    for i in range(1,len(side)):
        if side[i].true():
            print('Congrats')
        elif side[i].false():
            print('Try again')
```

And when it gets to this evaluate function, **it gives the error of "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '+'" and I am not too sure what this means and how to solve.**

```
def solve():
    pass
```

This function "solve" I was going to get to later after I have fixed the problems in the functions before.

```
def main():
    print("22-11x4 =", compute("22-11x4"),"(expect 44)")
    print("+11x4 =", compute("+11x4"),"(expect None)")
    print("22-11x4 ?= 7x5+9", evaluate("22-11x4=7x5+9"),"(expect True)")
    print("solving 288/24x6=18x13x8 :", solve("288/24x6=18x13x8"))

main()
```

Comment: well I am new to python afterall..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `compute` function you wrote does operation by digit, also you forgot to do one, last operation after `for` was finished:

```
2 - 1 - 1 x 4 = 0
```

this why you got this return from the function

Here is the correct function

```
def compute(side):
    val = 0
    buf = 0
    lastop = '+'
    for i in range(0, len(side)):
        if side[i].isdigit():
            buf = buf * 10 + int(side[i])
        else:
            val = op(val, buf, lastop)
            lastop = side[i]
            buf = 0
    val = op(val, buf, lastop)
    return val


def op(val, buf, lastop):
    if lastop == '+':
        val += buf
    elif lastop == '-':
        val -= buf
    elif lastop == 'x':
        val *= buf
    elif lastop == '/':
        val /= buf
    return val
```

Also in your testing string:

```
print("+11x4 =", compute("+11x4"),"(expect None)")
```

why do you expect None? it should be 44?

PS. this function could be improved yet, but I had no time to do it. anyway it works.

Comment: Thank you it works great for the compute function. But I'm getting this error for evaluate, "evaluate() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

Comment: this is a different kind of error, not related to this question. I think you have defined the function inside a class? in this way all functions should have one parameter, check the python documentation about class function definition.